# xpath get following siblings from current up to a certain point

Tags: python, xpath

here is the html:

```
   <a href="" target="_blank">title</a>
    <br>
    text
    <br>
    more text
    </p>
    <a href="" target="_blank">title2</a>
    more more text
    </p>
    <a href="" target="_blank">title3</a>
```

I currently have selected one of the a elements and want to get the text up to the next a sibling element, there could be one or more text nodes.

I don't know the text titles beforehand.

```
xpath('./following-sibling::br/text()')
```

I have tried this also:

```
xpath('.//*[preceding-sibling::p]following-sibling::text()')
```

**Expected output:** `['text','more text']`

Answer (score 0):

selecting all a elements and all text elements then iterating through checking if it is a a tag, if not then append string and start a new tag for each new a element:

```
tree.xpath('//a[@target="_blank"] | //a[@target="_blank"]/../text()')
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what you need.

```
   xpath('.//preceding-sibling::br[following-sibling::p]/text()')
```

Comment: Doesn't work: lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid expression. You can't have a * next to preceding-sibling like that...